# Performance degrade with spring-data-cassandra

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

We have migrated from thrift to cql and have used spring-data-cassandra.

Load test performance results are too bad after changes, specifically for timeseries read which is around 30 thousand rows.

Can someone guide if we are missing something that is causing this issue.

We were able to achieve desired results around 30-40 times faster. if we use spring-data-cassandra but don't do entity mapping. We observed threads getting blocked while doing entity mapping for each row. Spring-data do classloader to load entity class for each result row.

Changes we made were instead of specifying List of entity as return of select query we  made it List of Object.

**Slow Code**

```
 @Query("select * from \"InstrumentTimeSeries\" where key = ?0 and column1 >= ?1 and column1 <= ?2")
List<InstrumentTimeSeriesEntity> findByKeyAndRangeColumn1(ByteBuffer key, long columnValue1, long columnValue2);

 instrumentTimeSeriesRepository.findByKeyAndRangeColumn1(SRL_KEY.toByteBuffer(key), interval.getStartMillis(), interval.getEndMillis()).forEach(entity -> builder.addTick(entity.getColumn1(), SRL_DBL.fromByteBuffer(entity.getValue())));
```

**Fast Code** .

```
@Query("select * from \"InstrumentTimeSeries\" where key = ?0 and column1 >= ?1 and column1 <= ?2")
List<Object> findByKeyAndRangeColumn1(ByteBuffer key, long columnValue1, long columnValue2); }

instrumentTimeSeriesRepository.findByKeyAndRangeColumn1(SRL_KEY.toByteBuffer(key), interval.getStartMillis(), interval.getEndMillis()).forEach(row -> builder.addTick(((Row)row).getLong(1), SRL_DBL.fromByteBuffer(((Row)row).getBytes(2))));
```